# Sugar Orm just return the default value after saving new data in the new added column(upgrading Sugar Orm)

Tags: android, sugarorm

I want to add a new column `anotherValue` to my table `AnotherTable`.

I have read [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574233/how-to-upgrade-database-with-sugar-orm) and the SugarORM documentation, but when I save new data, and want to get `anotherValue` later, it just returns 0.

[image: sql screenshot]

Comment: The right syntax isn't `alter table another_table add column another_value interger `? you are missing `column` on your query

Comment: I have used column keyword too,but no difference @B.M

Answer (score 0):

The datatype needs to be `INT`, not `integer`, and you need the `COLUMN` keyword:

```
ALTER TABLE another_table ADD COLUMN another_value INT;
```

I actually wrote the (accepted) answer you linked to, I suggest you follow it more closely!

If you're still having trouble, please turn on SugarORM logging and post what is output when you save & load data. Additionally, try using a table & column name without underscore, to rule out SugarORM's name conversion causing issues.